# Como pegar a url da página pai de um iframe sem estar no mesmo domínio?

Tags: javascript, url, iframe, cross-domain

Pesquisei sobre postMessage, mas só encontrei exemplos de redimensionamento de iframe.

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de pegar a URL da página principal onde meu iframe está inserido usando esse método ou algum outro.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o seguinte:

```
var parentURL = window != window.parent ? document.referrer : null;
```

Quando sua página é carregada em um iframe, `window` é diferente de `window.parent`. Nesse caso, `document.referrer` terá a URL da página que carregou seu `iframe`.